# How can I see theme variation images in Keynote?

Tags: keynote

I was emptying the trash and noticed some images in a "recovered files" directory named something like `sotryboard-paper-green-flat.tiff` with variations for colour, gradients, etc. - These seemed to be variations of the default background and shape-fill images for the Keynote "Storyboard" theme, I had recently been making a Keynote using that theme so I figured it was some temporary files relating to that. "Great!" I thought, "I'll go and check out how to use those variations later."

So now back in Keynote using the Storyboard theme, when I create shapes they have a blue (tiled) fill-image and if I select <kbd>Choose...</kbd> it takes me to my own `PresentationAssets` directory from where I've loaded up images before. I don't know where to look for these built-in textures which are designed to fit with the theme, how do I find and use these images?

Answer (score 1):

The built-in files for Keynote are stored within the package. Go to:

> `/Applications/iWork '09/Keynote.app/Contents/Resources`

EDIT: The theme files themselves, at least on my machine running iWork '09, boxed version, are stored here:

```
/Library/Application Support/iWork '09/Frameworks/SFRendering.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Frames
```

Each theme contains a file with a suffix of `sfrframe`. Inside that file are the images for each theme.

Also under `/Resources` is a folder called `/Themes`. Within it are several theme files, shared images, etc. Each theme has several `.kth` files, which contain theme files and metadata.

Comment: I have Keynote from the Mac app-store, not the iWork version. It's at `/Applications/Keynote.app` but the `Contents/Resources` contains the app-bundle resources as I'd expect (the icons and graphics used in the app itself, on the tool-bar, inspector, etc.).

Comment: I located `/Applications/Keynote.app/Contents/Frameworks/SFRendering.framework/Resources/Frames/Storyboard.sfrframe/Contents/Resources` but those are border-image components, not the coloured image-fills. Also I can't believe that you're supposed to navigate there from the choose-image dialogue in Keynote to change the fill.

Comment: After more rummaging with `find` I found `/Applications/Keynote.app/Contents/Resources/Fills/Textures/Bright.sfctex` has the storyboard-theme coloured textures. However, I can't "show package contents" from the open dialgoue to navigate there. I could copy them out of course, but what's the 'correct' way from within the Keynote GUI to use these themed textures?